# When is this estimate about L2-norms true?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $f$ be a function in $L^2(U)$ where $U$ is some (not necessarily bounded) domain. For example, if $f$ is bounded, then for all $g \in L^2(U)$,

$$\|fg\|_{L^2(U)} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}\|g\|_{L^2(U)} = C\|g\|_{L^2(U)}. $$

Are there any other cases when this is true (i.e $f$ not necessarily bounded) or is this a necessary assumption?

Comment: You want to find under which constraints $\|fg\|_{L^2}$ is bounded by $C \|g\|_{L^2}$ (independently of $f$), am I right ?

Comment: Exactly, that’s the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $f \not \in L^\infty(U)$. Take $n \ge 1$, and let $E_n = \{x \in U : |f(x)| \ge n\}$. Then $\mu(E_n) > 0$, so if we let $g = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu(E_n)}}1_{E_n}$, then $||g||_2 = 1$ and $||fg||_2 \ge n$. So there is no $C$ with $||fg||_2 \le C||g||_2$.

Comment: Almost. Say  $U=\Bbb R$ and $f(t)=t$; then $g$ is "undefined" or $0$; we certainly don't have $||g||_2=1$...

Comment: **Note** btw the result is not true in an arbitrary measure space; hence a  correct solution must use some special property of Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich for your first comment, we are told that $f \in L^2$, so $\mu(E_n) < \infty$. For your second comment, I think it is just wrong. I think my solution is correct and doesn't use any special property of the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I missed $f\in L^2$, sorry. Yes, your solution is fine for the problem as stated. (My only excuse is that there's no reason to assume $f\in L^2$ here; but the result without that assumption is not true in an arbitrary measure space.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich what did you change to my answer? I can't spot a difference.

Comment: I added a blank line or two at the bottom. Because I'm not allowed to change a vote until the answer has been edited - turns out the system allows null edits...

Answer (score 2):

No, there are no other examples.

> > There exists $c$ such that $||fg||_2\le c||g||_2$ for all $g\in L^2$ if and only if $f\in L^\infty$.

Proof: One direction is obvious. For the other direction, suppose $||fg||_2\le c||g||_2$ for every $g\in L^2$. Fix $h\in L^1$ for a minute. There exists $g\in L^2$ with $h=g^2$. Then $$||f^2h||_1=||fg||_2^2\le c^2||g||_2^2=c^2||h||_1.$$So $h\mapsto\int f^2h$ defines a bounded linear functional on $L^1$.

Since we're in a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $(L^1)^*=L^\infty$. So $f^2\in L^\infty$, hence $f\in L^\infty$.